# Find the equation of the locus

Tags: analytic-geometry, locus

There's a diagram that shows a straight line $AB$ with $A=(-3,-3)$ and $B=(3,6)$.

> **Question:** Point $P$ moves such that its distance from $A$ is always twice its distance from $B$.
>
> Find the equation of the locus of $P$.

How to solve this?

Comment: Analytic geometry?  I.e. write down the equation satisfied by point $P = (x,y)$ in cartesian coordinates.  It's more likely you'll get the response you want if you show some effort to digest the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P=(x,y)$, then

\begin{align*}
  \sqrt{(x+3)^{2}+(y+3)^{2}} &= 2\sqrt{(x-3)^{2}+(y-6)^{2}} \\
  (x+3)^{2}+(y+3)^{2} &= 4[(x-3)^{2}+(y-6)^{2}] \\
  x^2+y^2+6x+6y+18 &= 4(x^2+y^2-6x-12y+45) \\
  0 &= 3x^2+3y^2-30x-54y+162 \\
  x^2+y^2-10x-18y+54 &=0\\
(x-5)^2+(y-9)^2&=52
\end{align*}

which is a circle with centre $(5,9)$ and radius $2\sqrt{13}$.

[image]

Comment: pointed out that the solution is a circle, if you don't like it, roll back.

Comment: @miracle173 ....Thank you very much for solving my question

Comment: @Ng Chung Tak ...thank you very much for solving my question

Comment: @miracle173 ...can you help to solve this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861204/find-a-the-coordinate-of-a-missing-point-r-in-quadrilateral